# Оконная система в .NET

Tags: .net, c#

В данный момент пишу на WPF (.NET 3.5). Писал на WinForms (.NET 2.0). А какая оконная система была в .NET 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

WinForms

WPF появился в третьем дотнете

Comment: Не подскажите, что было доступно в версии 1.0? Мне необходимо реализовать приложение именно с условием, что оно будет запускаться на .NET 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

> Не подскажите, что было доступно в версии 1.0? Мне необходимо реализовать приложение именно с условием, что оно будет запускаться на .NET 1.0.

Сложно сказать, что было "доступно" в .NET 1.0. Могу только сказать, что приложение придется писать/компилировать именно для .NET 1.0. 
Если мне память не изменяет, то для этого Вам нужно будет поставить visual studio 2003, либо 2005 + бубен (http://msbee.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Во втором дотнете из того, чем я активно пользуюсь, появился DataGridView и BindingSource.

Но, вообще говоря, там наиболее принципиальное нововведение - это поддержка Generic-типов. В первом дотнете все подобные вещи делались через object. Плюс ещё некоторые мелочи вроде анонимных методов и итераторов.